How to escape double quotes inside Azure Search Search.Ismatch Phrase Search Operator
@Matthew Gotteiner (tagging you for your answer found here (azuresearch search.ismatch is ignoring "1" at the end))
I'm running into a bit of a corner case that I'm struggling to solve. I'm using search.IsMatch() to allow user input to filter with "contains/Starts With/Endswith"
Below is a "contains" example (part of a larger filter).
    ((search.ismatch('/.*"search Text".*/', 'fieldName', 'full','any')))

This search works as expected and returns the filtered documents.
However, if I need to search a string with a double quote, then I'm having trouble figuring out how to escape that double quote when it's inside a phrase search operator.
I've tried the standard methods of escaping in every way I can think, but I can't seem to find a way to allow a phrase search operator that contains a double quote.
Am I missing something obvious? Is this even possible?
Thanks for any guidance!

Add the sample data you are trying this query.
